# C++ fast log-normal cdf approximation

Tags: c++, cdf

In C++ I want to create a function that takes a vector of numbers as input and output a vector of CDF values. The following is my attempt:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/lognormal.hpp>

vector<double> lognormCDF(vector<double>& input, double sigma)
{
    vector<double> output(input.size());
    boost::math::lognormal lognormDistr(0, sigma);

    for (size_t i = 0; i != input.size(); ++i)
    {
        output[i] = boost::math::cdf(lognormDistr, input[i]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

The above code works but I need it to be faster.

The following is some background information on how the function is going to be used:

- The input vector is not sorted and always positive.
- The input vector is typically 250 to 500 elements long.
- The sigma value can be from 0.14 to 1.4
- The CDF output is going to be in the range 0.000001 to 0.999999
- The CDF output only needs to be accurate to the nearest 0.000001

I'm just wondering whether there is a faster way to implement the above?

I'm also wondering if I sort the input vector, is there a faster way to calculate the lognormal CDF output vector?

Comment: The normal CDF usually uses spline polynomial approximation. You can use a similar technic in that case. You should check how  `boost::math::cdf ` does it.

if you want to make it faster you can use less spline polynomial.

Comment: Why not a multithread implementation? Looks easy enough to do, you can actually do it lock-free

Comment: You could try using `float`s.